# How do I set up a click method for a MenuStripItem

Tags: c#

I'm making a small game for myself and my family using a MenuStrip as the action commands in the combat.  However, I can't quite figure out how to set up the Click function for the magic.  Because the menustrip starts off mostly blank, I can't both create the list of spells and targets, and set up the click methods for those spells.  I'm at a bit of an impasse...

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56zov.png)

```
    string[] Spells = { };
    string[] Elements = { };
    string[] Targets = { };
    double[] Power = { };
    double[] ManaCost = { };

    StreamReader strReader = null;

            try
            {
                FileStream flsStream = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\Spells.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                strReader = new StreamReader(flsStream);
                while (strReader.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    string line = strReader.ReadLine();
                    string[] lines = line.Split(':');

                    Array.Resize(ref Spells, Spells.Length + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref Elements, Elements.Length + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref Targets, Targets.Length + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref Power, Power.Length + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref ManaCost, ManaCost.Length + 1);

                    Spells[Spells.Length - 1] = lines[0];
                    Elements[Elements.Length - 1] = lines[1];
                    Targets[Targets.Length - 1] = lines[2];
                    Power[Power.Length - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(lines[3]);
                    ManaCost[ManaCost.Length - 1] = Convert.ToDouble(lines[4]);
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < Spells.Length; x++)
                {
                    mnuMagic.DropDownItems.Add(Spells[x]);
                    mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].Name = string.Format("tsmi{0}", Spells[x]);
                    mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].Text += string.Format(", {0} MP", ManaCost[x]);
                    if (Targets[x] == "Single")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (Foe1.Status != "Dead")
                            {
                                if (Foe1.Health > Foe1.MaxHealth / 2)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe1, imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                                else if (Foe1.Health > Foe1.Health / 4)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe1, imgEnemyStatus.Images[1]);
                                else
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe1, imgEnemyStatus.Images[2]);
                            }
                            if (Foe2.Status != "Dead")
                            {
                                if (Foe2.Health > Foe2.MaxHealth / 2)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe2, imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                                else if (Foe2.Health > Foe2.Health / 4)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe2, imgEnemyStatus.Images[1]);
                                else
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe2, imgEnemyStatus.Images[2]);
                            }
                            if (Foe3.Status != "Dead")
                            {
                                if (Foe3.Health > Foe3.MaxHealth / 2)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe3, imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                                else if (Foe3.Health > Foe3.Health / 4)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe3, imgEnemyStatus.Images[1]);
                                else
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe3, imgEnemyStatus.Images[2]);
                            }
                            if (Foe4.Status != "Dead")
                            {
                                if (Foe4.Health > Foe4.MaxHealth / 2)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe4, imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                                else if (Foe4.Health > Foe4.Health / 4)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe4, imgEnemyStatus.Images[1]);
                                else
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe4, imgEnemyStatus.Images[2]);
                            }
                            if (Foe5.Status != "Dead")
                            {
                                if (Foe5.Health > Foe5.MaxHealth / 2)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe5, imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                                else if (Foe5.Health > Foe5.Health / 4)
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe5, imgEnemyStatus.Images[1]);
                                else
                                    (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(strFoe5, imgEnemyStatus.Images[2]);
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    else if (Targets[x] == "Ally")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(Fighter1.Name,imgEnemyStatus.Images[0]);
                            if (Fighter2.Name != null)
                                (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(Fighter2.Name);
                            if (Fighter3.Name != null)
                                (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(Fighter3.Name);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    else if (Targets[x] == "All")
                    {
                        (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("All Enemies");
                    }
                    else if (Targets[x] == "Team")
                        (mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("All Allies");

                    if (Elements[x] == "Fire")
                        mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    else if (Elements[x] == "Water")
                        mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    else if (Elements[x] == "Earth")
                        mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 0);
                    else if (Elements[x] == "Wind")
                        mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                    if (ManaCost[x] > Fighter1.Mana) { mnuMagic.DropDownItems[x].Enabled = false; }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, the code in use and your screen shot does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start dividing your code into subclasses. It will be very helpfull, even for little games. Here is a little bit of code I fiddled together. It does not handle everything you have, but you can easily extend that functionality. If you need additional informations, please tell me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private double CurrentMana { get; set; } = 50;
    private List<BasicSpell> m_lstSpells = new List<BasicSpell>();
    private List<BasicTarget> m_lstTargets = new List<BasicTarget>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Init();

        try
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem tsmiMagic = new ToolStripMenuItem("Magic");

            foreach (BasicSpell spell in m_lstSpells)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem tsmiSpell = spell.ToToolStripMenuItem();

                if (spell.CanHitAllEnemies)
                {
                    ToolStripItem tsiAll = tsmiSpell.DropDownItems.Add("All");
                    tsiAll.Click += (sender, arguments) => m_lstTargets.ForEach((target) => TryCastSpell(spell, target));
                }
                else { } // This spell can not hit all enemies

                for (int i = 0; i < m_lstTargets.Count; i++)
                {
                    BasicTarget target = m_lstTargets[i];

                    ToolStripItem tsiTarget = tsmiSpell.DropDownItems.Add($"Target {i}: {target.Name}");
                    tsiTarget.Image = target.StatusImage;
                    tsiTarget.Click += (sender, arguments) => TryCastSpell(spell, target);
                }

                tsmiMagic.DropDownItems.Add(tsmiSpell);
            }

            m_tsCombatOptions.Items.Add(tsmiMagic);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{ex}");
        }
    }

    private void TryCastSpell(BasicSpell spell, BasicTarget target)
    {
        if (!spell.Cast(target))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"You can not cast this spell with your current mana!");
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        m_lstSpells.Add(new Fireball());
        m_lstSpells.Add(new Fireball());
        m_lstSpells.Add(new Fireball());
        m_lstSpells.Add(new Fireball());

        m_lstTargets.Add(new Monster("Reißzahn", 500));
        m_lstTargets.Add(new Monster("Reißzahn", 500));
        m_lstTargets.Add(new Monster("Reißzahn", 500));
        m_lstTargets.Add(new Monster("Reißzahn", 500));
        m_lstTargets.Add(new Monster("Reißzahn", 500));
    }
}

// TODO: POWER?

[Flags]
public enum Element
{
    Fire = 0x0,
    Earth = 0x1,
    Water = 0x2,
    Wind = 0x4
}

public abstract class BasicSpell
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Element DamageType { get; set; }
    public double ManaCost { get; set; }
    public bool CanHitAllEnemies { get; set; } = false;

    public abstract bool Cast(BasicTarget target);

    public ToolStripMenuItem ToToolStripMenuItem()
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem tsmiSpell = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        tsmiSpell.Text = $"{this.Name}, {ManaCost} MP";

        return tsmiSpell;
    }
}

public class Fireball : BasicSpell
{
    public override bool Cast(BasicTarget target)
    {
        // TODO: Check if castable (maybe add caster as parameter)

        target.HP -= 500;
        return true;
    }
}

public abstract class BasicTarget
{
    public enum CombatStatus
    {
        Alive = 0,
        Dead = 1
    }

    public enum TargetRelation
    {
        Enemy = 0,
        Ally = 1
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double HP { get; set; }
    public CombatStatus Status { get; set; }
    public TargetRelation Relation { get; set; }

    public Image StatusImage => null;
}

public class Monster : BasicTarget
{
    public Monster(string strName, int nHP)
    {
        this.Name = strName;
        this.HP = nHP;
        this.Status = CombatStatus.Alive;
        this.Relation = TargetRelation.Enemy;
    }
}
```